# Python code to send dict keys to dataframe suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm scraping information from IMDb using OMDBAPI, and my code suddenly stopped working? It worked for days while I scraped and dealt with timeout issues, and the scraping is still working. But my code is supposed to send the info to a dataframe using dictionary keys, and that step seems to have suddenly stopped working?

Not really sure what to do as the code has worked before

```py
for Id in first_pass:
    movie = omdb.imdbid(Id, tomatoes=False, timeout=5)
    movie_set  = pd.DataFrame(movie, columns=movie.keys())
    df = pd.concat([df, movie_set], axis =0, sort=False)
```

The movie_set step is the one that seems to not be working. I enter the ID and get a dictionary that looks like:

```
{ 'title': 'Kommen und gehen',  
 'year': '1994',  
 'rated': 'N/A',  
 'released': 'N/A',  
 'runtime': '50 min',  
 'genre': 'Documentary',  
 'director': 'Lew Hohmann'  
}
```

But on the movie_set step, if I run that all I'm returned is a blank dataframe with the column names but no info.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax to convert a dictionary to a data frame.

```
movie_set = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movie, orient='index')
```

You also will want to change

```
df = pd.concat([df, movie_set], axis=1)
```

Since you want columns and rows flipped

```
movie_set = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(movie, orient='index').T
df = pd.concat([df, movie_set], axis=0)
```

Comment: That's definitely not what I want. This returns movie_set as a long dataframe that's 37x1 . I want a 1x37 dataframe but orient='columns' returns an empty header for a DF with no rows

Comment: All you have to do is movie_set.T to flip it.